# Different request object in Next.js middleware between Apollo Server Resolver (Next.js 13 + Apollo Server 4)

Tags: next.js13, apollo-server

I want to access the request information that can be referenced in Next.js' middleware in Apollo-Server's Resolver or middleware.

However, since the request information accessible in Next.js middleware and the request information that can be referenced in Apollo-Server's middleware or resolver are different, it is not possible to use getToken (next-auth/jwt) in Apollo-Server.

Is there a way to receive Nextauth information from Apollo Server's Resolver or Middleware?

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [...],
});

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler<NextRequest>(server, {
  context: async (req: NextRequest) => ({ req }),
});
```

In Next.js middleware,

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  ...
  console.log(request); 
  /*
     cookies: RequestCookies {"next-auth.csrf-token":{"name":"next-auth.csrf-token","value": ..
     geo:{},
     ...
  /*


  const token = await getToken({ req: request });
  console.log(token); // {sub: '2', iat: 1, exp: 0,  jti: ''}
  ...
}
```

In Apollo-Server resolver,

```
  @Query(() => [User])
  async users(
    @Ctx("req") req: NextRequest,
  ) {
    console.log(req);
    /*
      <ref *2> IncomingMessage {
       _readableState: ReadableState {
       objectMode: false,
       highWaterMark: 16384,
       buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
       length: 0,
    */

    const token = await getToken({ req });
    /* null */    

    ...
    return users;
  }
```